# How can I check the first letter of each item in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x

I'm building a pig latin translator and I can't figure out how to identify the first letter of the entered words. I've converted the input to an array with each item being a new word, but how do I select each first letter of each item to determine if it's a consonant/vowel/etc.?

Comment: what have you tried to do before asking? show us the code

Comment: Strings are iterable like lists, you get their first letter in the same manner you would with a list of characters: `string[0]`

Comment: Another very Pythonic option would be to use `map` to go from a list of words to a list of characters: `map(lambda word: word[0], words)` (just be aware that in 3.x, `map` doesn't immediately return a list, and you have to wrap the final result in `list(...)` after transforming the data.)

Answer (score 4):

```
a = ['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence']
for word in a:
    print(word[0])
```

Output:
T
i
a
s

Answer (score 4):

```
words = ['apple', 'bike', 'cow']
```

Use list comprehension, that is, building a list from the contents of another:

```
firsts = [w[0] for w in words]
firsts
```

Output

```
['a','b','c']
```

Answer (score 0):

using list cmprh with checking if a word not null

```
a = ['This', 'is', '', 'sentence']
[w[0] for w in a if w]
```

Output :

```
['T', 'i', 's']
```